# Unordered list dropping to the next line

Tags: css

[image]I have an unordered list that has a problem.  As you can see below I have the list set to 100% of the container.  The problem is that the list items all arent on the same line.  The 5th element drops to the next line.  The list items are set to 20% of the ul and there are 5 li's.  Assuming my math is correct that adds up to 100%.  Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

### HTML

```
<div class="navi">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Get The<br>Facts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Professional<br>Education &amp; Resources</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Understanding<br>Addiction</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">More About<br>The Blunt Truth</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.navi ul                                    { width:100%; }
.navi ul > li                               { background:#347311; width:20%; display:inline-block; }
.navi ul > li > a                           { font-size:20px; color: #f4f6cf; font-weight: 700; }
```

Comment: please share your html as well

Comment: HTML added. See revision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the font-size on your .navi ul to 0px.
The way your html is setup you have spaces between each list item so it ends up being 20% + space + 20% + space, etc instead of them being tightly packed.

You already have a font-size set on your links so they wont be affected.

**CSS:**

```
.navi ul                                    { width:100%; font-size:0px; }
```

That worked for me, check out my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joncampbell/m96ckp1r/) as an example.

Comment: Also, is it possible to center the anchor element inside of the li?  I need the text to be aligned left like it is, but center it.  I've tried `margin:0 auto` and made the a tag `display:block`

Comment: I'm not sure visually what you are trying to do.
Are you wanting it centered horizontally or vertically?
Do you possible just want some padding on it?

Comment: Imagine you just centered the text.  Its in the center of the li right?  I need to use text-align:left though. So basically centering the text in the li but having it left aligned.  Does that make any more sense.

Comment: So why not just use text-align:center?
Sorry, I am not understanding what you want to do.

Comment: That still doesn't make much sense.

If you want it to have more space away from the left and right sides use some padding, you may need to adjusts your widths at the same time.

See this [updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joncampbell/m96ckp1r/1/)

Comment: Cool, so I was able to add an image to the original post.  See above.  Maybe this will help.

Comment: So yeah, you need some padding, like I linked a few minutes ago.
Interesting that your example the li aren't actually 20% each.

Comment: Yea its from some designer.  I am just cleaning it up that's all.  The image is from a PSD.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72809/discussion-between-joncampbell-and-jesders88).

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you need to do:
Add it to the css of **ul**,

> **display:flex;**

Here's a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8c6p9r6L/)**

**CSS**:

```
.navi ul                                    { width:100%;display:flex; }  //change here
.navi ul > li                               { background:#347311; width:20%;display:inline-block;  }
.navi ul > li > a                           { font-size:20px; color: #f4f6cf; font-weight: 700; }
```

.

**UPDATE:**

Based on your update, there is another solution.
Check this new **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8c6p9r6L/4/).**

All you need is to play with the **display** property. You can check this **[source](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)** for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Adding in `float:left;` to the `li` makes them align.

http://jsfiddle.net/peterdotjs/44jbt6jt/

Comment: Doesnt this kind of make `display:inline-block;` pointless then?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with space between the LI tags with inline-block is used. there are multiple solutions to it. See [css-tricks link](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

my choice would be to set font size for the UL as 0 and set for LI the required font size and set word-break: break-all to A tag.

```css
.navi ul { width:100%; font-size:0px;}
.navi ul > li { background:#347311; width:20%; display:inline-block; font-size:20px;}
.navi ul > li > a { font-size:20px; color: #f4f6cf; font-weight: 700; word-break: break-all; font-size:20px;}
```

```html
<div class="navi">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Get The<br>Facts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Professional<br>Education &amp; Resources</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Understanding<br>Addiction</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">More About<br>The Blunt Truth</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
.navi ul            { width:100%; }
.navi ul li       { background:#347311; width:20%;float:left; display:inline-block; }
.navi ul li a  { font-size:20px; color: #f4f6cf; font-weight: 700; }
```

Please try this.